# keywords (initial, revert, etc) in padding and margin shorthand properties

Tags: css

Here is a padding shorthand property:

```
selector {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

which is the same as

```
selector {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

I have tried to use the same shorthand as in the first example with keywords (`initial`, `inherit`, `unset`, `revert`) instead of numbers, but this doesn't work. May be there is some workaround or I simply don't know something very simple?

```
selector {
  padding: revert 1em; /* doesn't work */
}

selector {
  padding: 'revert' 1em; /* and this too */
}
```

Comment: those keywords are only valid as single value, they cannot be combined with other values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `padding-inline` to target only left and right side

```
padding-inline: 1em;
```

```css
div {
  padding-inline: 1em;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>box</div>
```